# change local directory while connected to ftp server (command line)

Tags: command-line, ftp

When we are connected to an FTP server (from command line), How can we change the local directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find that with most of the commands, prefixing an `l` will apply it to the local, and a non-`l` applies to remote.  For example:

- `pwd` on remote and `lpwd` on local.
- `cd` on remote and `lcd` on local.